# Instagram Wordpress Gallery Sortable by Name

Tags: wordpress, sorting, instagram, gallery

I need to show Instagram posts on a Wordpress website, as a tiled gallery, and to be able to let the website user sort the posts by name.
Any ideas the easiest way to get this done please?

I've looked for Instagram plugins, but I can only find ones which simply feed the posts in. I wonder if I need to look at it from another perspective, maybe even in reverse (?), so I add an image to the gallery and it posts to the Instagram account (?). Stumped by this one, so any help much appreciated.

Comment: If i am not mistaken IG have no sort support except #tags,categories etc but sorting by title , date or any other similar data i dont think its possible. I may be wrong as i did some projects 2020 with IG. In limitations section says ordering results not supported - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/